# Sum of powers of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory, integers

The equation $k^2 + (k+1)^2 + (k+2)^2 = (k+3)^2 + (k+4)^2$ has unique positive integer solution $k = 10$.

For which integers $n > 2$, if any, does $k^n + (k+1)^n + (k+2)^n = (k+3)^n + (k+4)^n$ have a positive integral solution $k$?

*Note:* The question is motivated by an Abstruse Goose cartoon (http://abstrusegoose.com/63) which I first saw at:  http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/quotes.html

Comment: Looking like *[murray](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/32337/murray)'s Last Theorem*.

Comment: The question doesn't quite look like any of the common generalization or variants of FLT that I've encountered.

Comment: @murray: I believe that Subhadeep is joking, and that he means that your question looks very difficult, and may not have an elementary solution. :)

Comment: I fully appreciated the point @Subhadeep Day made when he made it!

Comment: Well, I have proved it impossible for $3 \leq n \leq 56$.  Of course, that is not even a start...

Comment: @Mark Fischler: Of course one can directly check for $n = 3$ and $n = 4$ by solving the equation to see there are no integral solutions. How did you handle $5 \leq n \leq 56$?

Comment: Worth doing this numerically to find the real value of $k> 1$ that solves the thing for a fixed $n.$ For small $n,$  $ k > 6n-2.$ When $n=9, $ evidently $k = 52.5098.$ The fractional part seems to be increasing linearly, so I would expect $k$ to be near an integer for $n$ about 15 or so. Might be possible to solve for real valued $k$ in Mathematica.

Comment: Using `NSolve` in  *Mathematica*, I'm not seeing any positive integral solutions for $k$ with $n$ in the range $5 \leq p \leq 200$.